# Change NSwagStudio serialization setting to allow for Nulls

Tags: nswagstudio

Is there a way to change the settings in NSwagStudio so that when the JSON serialization setting outputs as `Newtonsoft.Json.Required.AllowNull` instead of `Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Always`?

I currently have the property manually changed to allow for nulls.

```
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("returnCode", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Always)]
public int ReturnCode { get; set; }
```

And I need it to be:

```
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("returnCode", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.AllowNull)]
public int ReturnCode { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

It will not be nullable inside the generated code if it is not nullable at the API-spec

**API spec example:**

```
    ReturnCode:
      type: integer
      nullable: true
```

Comment: And how can this be specified at the source code?

Comment: The source code specification is written above in the question `Newtonsoft.Json.Required.AllowNull`